# serve html5 video ads using VAST

Tags: html, flash, ads, vast

Does anyone know if (and how) it is possible to serve HTML5 video ads using VAST (Video Ad Serving Template)? I know that flash (swf) videos are supported, but I'm not sure if I need to jump through hoops in order to wrap my HTML5 video source with a flash wrapper, or is there a simple way to make HTML5 videos support VAST?

Please advise :)

Amit

Answer (score 0):

Google provides the IMA SDK which handles VAST ads, check out their [website](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/). Is is available for the plain HTML5 video player and for VideoJS.